# this.title returning as Undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to get my bot to "dynamically" get the name of a command.
`title` is defined in `module.exports` as the name of the command that will show up in the Embed; however in 1 specific command where I get a joke from an API, `this.title` returns as Undefined instead of the command's name.

It only happens in this command.
I've tried using just `title` however that just returns "node".
What did I do wrong? 
Code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { title } = require("process");
const config = require("../data.json");

module.exports = {
    name: "dadjoke",
    title: "Dad Joke",
    description: "A (not so) very funny dadjoke.",
    execute(client, message, args) {
        const https = require('https');
        const url = "icanhazdadjoke.com";
        var options = {
            host: url,
            port: 443,
            path: "/",
            headers: {"Accept":"application/json", "User-Agent":"crazyBot (https://github.com/acrazytown/crazybot)"}
        }

        function getData(options) {
            https.get(options, (resp) => {
            let data = '';

            resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data += chunk;
            });

            resp.on('end', () => {
                const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor(config.crazyBot.settings.accent_color)
                    .setAuthor("crazyBot", config.crazyBot.settings.icon_url)
                    .setTitle(this.title)
                    .setDescription(JSON.parse(data).joke)
                    .setFooter(`Powered by ${url}`);
                
                message.channel.send(embed);
            });

            }).on("error", (err) => {
            console.log("Error: " + err.message);
            });
        }

        getData(options)
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you pass the accumulated string `data` through `JSON.parse()` to get the actual joke; maybe that's also where the title is located. It's not clear why you expect "title" to be a property of the exported main object.

Comment: I've just checked and there is no title in `data`, only the joke, id of the joke, and status. I expected `this.title` to work because it works in every other command, only not in this one.

Comment: You call `getData()` without any object reference, so `this` itself will be `undefined`.

Comment: How could I get the title then? Sorry if this is a really dumb question, I'm still learning JS

Comment: Well if "title" is supposed to be the value of that "title" property in the exported object ("Dad Joke"), then you could add a parameter to `getData()` and pass `this.title` in to the function, or simply have a `title` variable in `execute()` that gets a copy of the "title" property of the object (like, `let title = this.title;`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the function `getData()` doesn't have an object reference, the value of `this` within the function is undefined whereas the value of `this` within `execute()` is defined as the object being exported. One simple solution to this is to use `Function.bind()` to set the `this` keyword of `getData()` to the object reference.

This is how that would look in your `execute()` function:

```
execute(client, message, args) {
    const https = require('https');
    const url = "icanhazdadjoke.com";
    var options = {
        host: url,
        port: 443,
        path: "/",
        headers: {"Accept":"application/json", "User-Agent":"crazyBot (https://github.com/acrazytown/crazybot)"}
    }

    var getData = function(options) {
        https.get(options, (resp) => {
        let data = '';

        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
        });

        resp.on('end', () => {
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(config.crazyBot.settings.accent_color)
                .setAuthor("crazyBot", config.crazyBot.settings.icon_url)
                .setTitle(this.title)
                .setDescription(JSON.parse(data).joke)
                .setFooter(`Powered by ${url}`);
            
            message.channel.send(embed);
        });

        }).on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("Error: " + err.message);
        });
    }.bind(this);

    getData(options)
}
```

Relevant resources:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind